# kendo grid inline Create datepicker value is not coming to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm new to `Kendo` and working on task which is CRUD using kendo grid with inline edit, but I am facing issue with create operation when I try to insert the data the date field does not working it brings **{1/1/0001 12:00Am}** value to the controller, I don't know whats happening here because I have used date format with date picker but issue still persist. help me solve this issue thanks.

**The code for the grid is :**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Home/LoadEmployeesAsyc",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "/Home/UpdateEmployeesAsyc",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "/Home/DelectEmployeesAsyc",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "/Home/CreateEmployeeAsyc",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: {type: "number"},
                        Name: {type: "string"},
                        Age: {type: "number"},
                        JoiningDate: {type: "Date"},
                        DepartmentId: {type: "number"},
                        profilePic: {type: "string"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            height: 550,
            sortable: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            groupable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            columns: [{
                    field: "Id",
                    title: "Employee Code"
                },
                {
                    field: "Name",
                    title: "Name"
                },

                {
                    field: "Age",
                    title: "Age"
                },

                {
                    field: "JoiningDate",
                    title: "Joining Date",
                    width: 100,
                    format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                    editor: dateEditor
                },
                {
                    field: "DepartmentId",
                    title: "Department Code",
                },

                {
                    field: "ProfilePic",
                    title: "Picture",
                    template:
                            '<img height="50" width="50" src="../Content/Images/#:data.ProfilePic#"/>'
                },
                {command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px"}],
            editable: "inline"
        });

    });

    function dateEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input type="text" name="JoiningDate" id="JoiningDate"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDatePicker({
                    format: "MM/dd/yyyy"
                });
    }
</script>
```

**Code of grid :**

```
public JsonResult LoadEmployeesAsyc()
{
    var employees = employeeRepository.GetAll();
    return new JsonNetResult() { Data = employees };
}

public JsonResult CreateEmployeeAsyc(Employee employee)
{
    employeeRepository.Create(employee);
    var employees = employeeRepository.GetAll();
    return new JsonNetResult() { Data = employees };
}
```

[image: Console snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found solution for my issue:
I have used  parameterMap function convert date to this **"MM/dd/yyyy"** format

```html
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation != "read") {
                        var d = new Date(options.JoiningDate);
                        options.JoiningDate = kendo.toString(new Date(d), "MM/dd/yyyy");
                        return options;
                    }
```

Put the below script in schema model

```
JoiningDate: { type: 'date', format: "MM/dd/yyyy" },
```

and define format in date column :

```
{
                           field: "JoiningDate",
                           title: "Joining Date",
                           format: '{0:MM/dd/yyyy}',
                           width: 100
                       },
```